# Generate time stamps in a specific time zone

Tags: javascript, timezone, unix-timestamp

I almost blamed a issue was having on MS testing a page i made, but the clock in the virtual machine had the wrong time zone
anyway i have this line in a AJAX request, i use this to monitor the system to make sure it has not stopped working, it is should never be over a few seconds old (not counting clock variation) so a hour old clearly means the server side software crashed

```
diff = Math.round( ( new Date().getTime() - new Date(httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")).getTime() ) / 1000 );
```

how can i generate these stamps in a neutral time zone like GMT 0

Comment: you should make a response of server time, instead of checking `last-modified` response header!

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to look at all the headers available and I saw a date one

```
age = new Date( httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Date")) .getTime() - new Date( httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified") ).getTime();
```

This way I can compare the servers date to the servers modified time